# where to find different types of items in a particular order_header_key IBM Sterling OMS

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query in STERLING database. I really wonder where to get the number of items ordered in a order.

1. I can get number of orders from `yfs_order_header` table but how to get how much quantity of of different items being ordered in each order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have yfs_order_line which is a hangoff enabled table and has the reference of yfs_order_header table. So there can be many order lines for a single order. So write a query to get the sum of order quantity from order lines table with order header as the condition. This will give you the number of quantities in an order if you group it with inventory_item_Id you ll get the no of quantities against each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of lines associated to an order with the next query:

select count(*)
from yfs_order_header yoh,
yfs_order_line yol
where and yoh.order_header_key=yol.order_header_key
and yoh.order_no='ORDER_NO'

If you want to sum all the quantity values for every line do the next query:
select sum(yol.original_ordered_qty)
from yfs_order_header yoh,
yfs_order_line yol
where yoh.order_header_key=yol.order_header_key
and yoh.order_no='ORDER_NO'